# Why in some comments there are white gaps (or blank spaces)?

Tags: bug, mathjax

I was wondering why in some comments there are white gaps (or blank spaces)?

My browser is Firefox version 43.0.4 (Ubuntu OS).

For example from question [Show that $d(x,y)$ in a metric on $X$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685488/show-that-dx-y-in-a-metric-on-x) I get the following display:

[image]

Comment: It's a MathJax rendering issue. The empty spaces are where there are formulae, and the size of the formulae was calculated so the text is where it ought to be, but for some reason the formulae aren't rendered. Typically, reloading the page helps. (Or anything that causes a re-rendering.)

Comment: @johnny09 could you try using the MathJax menu (rightclick any equation) to change the renderer and tell us which ones have problems?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Initially, the default I had was "HTML-CSS", and when I changed it to the "Common HTML" everything displayed nicely. Should I test the other options also?

Comment: @johnny09 that's a good start. The SVG is the only other important output. But I'll check it when I file the bug upstream. Thanks again.

Comment: @johnny09 I'm not able to reproduce this on FF 43.0.4, Ubuntu 15.10. I'm wondering if it's a broken component in the cache; does it help to clean the browser cache (or just the MathJax components)?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I am not sure if it matters but I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3. Also, yes it did help. I cleared my browser's cache, and then I visited the site where it displayed everything right. But when I reloaded again, the blank spaces appeared again. By the way, the SVG works fine (I tested it before I cleared my cache and after).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to comments, the easiest solution is switching the Math Renderer via

MathJax menu > Math Settings > Math Renderer > Common HTML

To get the MathJax menu, right-click any formula (Control-click on a Mac).

The Common HTML renderer [appears to be the future focus of MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/whitepaper-towards-mathjax-v3/), so we may as well use more of it and report any issues with *that* renderer.

Comment: I did this, it seems to improve things. Probably worth repeating that the "context menu" is found by placing the mouse on some formula and right-clicking. I had not the slightest clue that right clicking would do much of anything on this site.

Comment: Thank you..........

Comment: Apple mice have no "right click". What's the Apple equivalent to the right click?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Apparently you need to hold control and then click. (And this also works on Windows and Linux, by the way.)